# Determining user current location in IPhone and nearest locations from it

Tags: iphone, dictionary, geolocation

I am currently developing a mobile application for IPhone which consists a part that requires to determine the user current location and also the nearest locations ( as lat,long point stored in phone). I am having the following questions:

1- Does the user needs to be connected to the internet so his/her location can be determined by our application? Won't GPS devise sufficient to determine the user current location as lat,long?

2- Since we will be having some locations as lat,long stored in the application, is it possible to determine the nearest locations (e.g. within 5 km) from the user current location without having an internet connection?

If code sample can be provided to narrow down the answer for the above, that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm guessing the GPS needs to send and receive data through an internet connection. You can calculate nearest whatevers offline if you have the data (coordinates to stuff) stored locally.

Comment: You want in android or iphone

Comment: Since the user's phone is having a GPS device in his phone, why does the application need to connect to the internet since the GPS is supposed to determine the user current location in offline mode by default. In my question above, I am not meaning displaying the user current location in an online map (Google or Bing Map) but only determining the user current lat,long.f the user current location can be calculated without an internet connection, then surely finding the nearest locations (stored as lat,long in the phone) wont need an internet connection and can be determined by an equation

Answer (score 1):

well, for u r first question u need not required internet connection for fetching your current location.

For u r second question, well if u are able to get the co ordinates of your position(latitude,longitude) you said  `we will be having some locations as lat,long stored in the application` then you can compute the co ordinates and find the distance between them.

Use the following function for computing distance from coordinates

```
 public static float distFrom(float lat1, float lng1, float lat2, float lng2) {
    double earthRadius = 6371;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
               Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
               Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    return(float)(dist);
    }
```

Its a java implementation of the haversine formula. Use it for finding distance.

Comment: Thanks NejiHyuga for your promising answer. In this case, can you please give a coding example for calculating the user current location internally by the Phone GPS and without the need to connect to the internet? That is for both IOS and Android if possible

Answer (score 0):

yes you have to find the nearest location information  under 5 or something miles using the  google API ,with this API you ll find everything ..country info ,nearest location..ect

use this link :- http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%f,%f&output=json&oe=utf8&sensor=true_or_false&key=ABQIAAAAO_WEDXjKUGDDHu8iB2FQ-xTFGipc9T1i1tjtezgvz0dWKwv3jxTjn5y1VrjIixtSrXmeMwiaCfxS8g

Comment: Thanks Nivrit Gupta, but why do I need to use Google API to find the nearest locations since these locations lat,long are stored offline in the phone database?

Comment: I am still looking forward a confirmed answer for this post two questions :)

Comment: Hello friend please use the following link to download the demo https://github.com/heardrwt/GeocoderDemo ...after that install this demo in your device with the help of your current location lat,log you will find the nearest location and other related information ..if you have any problem then let me know

Comment: will apple, reject my app if i use this api in my project ? i am also looking for the same result. i want to find nearest locations from my current location.

Comment: ok if you do not use the google API then please use the custom webservices to find nearest locations from my current location